# Enable XSD as Type Definition Language is Disabled

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, xsd, schema, contract-first

I came from this question : [How to install Contract-First Tool in VisualStudio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385679/how-to-install-contract-first-tool-in-visualstudio-2012)

When I tried to perform the steps mentioned by the answer of that question, which is also what is mentioned in the topic [Contract-First Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674270.aspx), I faced the following problem: The options **Enable XSD as type definition language** and **Validate WCF configuration when building the project** are *disabled*.

The XML Schema generated is valid and it was taken from the aforementioned tutorial.

Why is that happening?

[image: Options disabled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assembly needs to target .NET 4.5 for this option to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this (based on a hunch more than any scientific reasoning). Close your project and run Visual Studio as an administrator. (Ctrl + Shift + Enter when the shortcut is selected).

Then open the project and navigate to the properties screen again and let us know what's there.

It's the language ("***Enable*** XSD as...") that suggests to me that there may be some administrative privilege required to get this to work.

I'd imagine any subsequent instances would be fine then.

FWIW I maintain two separate shortcuts for VS, one with normal privileges and the other with elevated privileges.